# How to have dynamic property variable names in Spring XML include files?

Tags: java, spring

Let's say I have a Spring xml include file and it has some property variables in it like below.

```
<bean class="foo.Book">
    <property name="id" value="${foo.bar}" />
</bean>
```

This is obviously a very simple example. The real example is larger and more complex. Now imagine I have three different values of 'foo' that I'd like this include file loaded for: [a, b, c]. The ultimate end result would be equivalent to loading three different files each with the same bean as below.

```
<bean class="foo.Book">
    <property name="id" value="${a.bar}" />
</bean>

<bean class="foo.Book">
    <property name="id" value="${b.bar}" />
</bean>

<bean class="foo.Book">
    <property name="id" value="${c.bar}" />
</bean>
```

In other words I want three property variables resolved and the beans instantiated with the values of those properties.

```
${a.bar}
${b.bar}
${c.bar}
```

However the values [a,b,c] are dynamic and creating three separate include files isn't an option due to bean duplication. How would you do this?

I've already thought about using system properties and spring expression language but those solutions only work if each include file is loaded in its own process. I want to load all three include files in one process but in reality only have one include file that is parameterised.

Many thanks.